# Post to an https rest endpoint using node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, https

I have a requirement, a Post request will be sent to Node.js and it has to be sent to a https rest endpoint with the same request body and return the response. I have tried using Http, node-rest-client npms. Those all seem to work for a http post request but not with https. Any help with code will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node-rest-client` actually supports HTTPS requests per the documentation.  You may need to specify a :443 port or add the `connection` option when initializing the client:

```
var options = {
    // proxy configuration
    proxy: {
        host: "proxy.foo.com", // proxy host
        port: 8080, // proxy port
        user: "ellen", // proxy username if required
        password: "ripley" // proxy pass if required
    },
    // aditional connection options passed to node http.request y https.request methods 
    // (ie: options to connect to IIS with SSL) 
    connection: {
        secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2,
        ciphers: 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM',
        honorCipherOrder: true
    },
    // customize mime types for json or xml connections
    mimetypes: {
        json: ["application/json", "application/json;charset=utf-8"],
        xml: ["application/xml", "application/xml;charset=utf-8"]
    },
    user: "admin", // basic http auth username if required
    password: "123", // basic http auth password if required
    requestConfig: {
        timeout: 1000, //request timeout in milliseconds
        noDelay: true, //Enable/disable the Nagle algorithm
        keepAlive: true, //Enable/disable keep-alive functionalityidle socket.
        keepAliveDelay: 1000 //and optionally set the initial delay before the first keepalive probe is sent
    },
    responseConfig: {
        timeout: 1000 //response timeout
    }
};
```

See https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client for details.

Comment: 'request' is also a great module for this kind of thing, which also supports https